# Problems with large numbers in Tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, tikzmath

I have a MWE as following.I build a matrix whose first column is 1's; second column is the square of each component of x; third column is the cube of the x component, and so on. I need to use `tikzmath` for another reasons.

When `xi` is small (`x<10`), work very well; however, when `xi` is negative or large (`x>100`), the problems occurs.

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.```

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}


\begin{document}


\tikzmath{
    \p=12;%número de pontos fornecidos
    \q=4;%número de parâmetros a serem ajustados
    \X{1}=-100;
    \X{2}=110;
    \X{3}=120;
    \X{4}=130;
    %
    function phi1(\x){%Funções da base
        \y = 1;
        return \y;
    };
    function phi2(\x){%Funções da base
        \y = \x;
        return \y;
    };
    %
    function phi3(\x){%Funções da base
        \y = \x*\x;
        return \y;
    };
    %
    function phi4(\x){%Funções da base
        \y = \x*\x*\x;
        return \y;
    };
    %
    function G(\x) {
       \u = phi1(\x); 
       \v = phi2(\x);
       \w = phi3(\x);
       \z = phi4(\x);
      return {\u,\v,\w,\z};
    };
    real \Matriz; int \i; int \j;
    for \i in {1,...,4}{
        for \j in {1,...,4}{
            \Matriz{\i,\j}={G(\X{\i})}[\fpeval{\j-1}];
        };
    };
}

A matriz $A$ é dada por: \\

$
A=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
     \Matriz{1,1}&\Matriz{1,2}  & \Matriz{1,3} & \Matriz{1,4}\\
     \Matriz{2,1}&\Matriz{2,2}  & \Matriz{2,3} & \Matriz{2,4}\\
     \Matriz{3,1}&\Matriz{3,2}  & \Matriz{3,3} & \Matriz{3,4}\\
     \Matriz{4,1}&\Matriz{4,2}  & \Matriz{4,3} & \Matriz{4,4}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

\end{document}
```

I have tried the library `fixedarithmeticpoint` but not solved.
The problem is the line `\Matriz{\i,\j}={G(\X{\i})}[\fpeval{\j-1}];`, but I am not how can I solve this, and why this occurs for only large and negative numbers.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: You submitted an edit whilst logged out presumably, I am not sure why an edit to your own question needed approval in the suggest edits queue, did you log out or create a new account?

Comment: Tikz manual s55.1: length calculations in `fixedpointarithmetic` are by PGF, which uses TeX (+\- 16k), which limits your input to max integer 25 (< cube root of 16k).

Comment: `\tikzmath` in `math` library is limited to TeX capacity also - manual s58.1.

Answer (score 1):

#### answer with a real "matrix" storage

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}

% store once and for all data for access
\xintAssignArray{-100}{110}{120}{130}\to\X


% store all computations for doing them only once
% syntax for retreival: \Matriz{i,j} where i = line, j = column starting at 1
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Matriz[1]{\Matriz@#1;}
\def\Matriz@#1#2,#3#4;{\csname
  % using \numexpr here to allow \Matriz{3,1+2} syntax
  % although usefulness is somewhat doubtful, but this
  % can however also be used with LaTeX \value{counter}, which
  % may be more useful
  Matriz\the\numexpr#1#2,\the\numexpr#3#4;\endcsname}
% line index, column index;
\xintFor#1 in {1, 2, 3, 4}\do{% #1 = line index
  \xintFor#2 in {1, 2, 3, 4}\do{% #2 = column index
    % use "column index minus 1" as exponent
    % let us not forget parentheses in case #1 is negative
    \expandafter\edef\csname Matriz#1,#2;\endcsname{\xinteval{(\X{#1})^(#2-1)}}%
}%
}
\makeatother


A matriz $A$ é dada por: \\

$
A=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
     \Matriz{1,1}&\Matriz{1,2}  & \Matriz{1,3} & \Matriz{1,4}\\
     \Matriz{2,1}&\Matriz{2,2}  & \Matriz{2,3} & \Matriz{2,4}\\
     \Matriz{3,1}&\Matriz{3,2}  & \Matriz{3,3} & \Matriz{3,4}\\
     \Matriz{4,1}&\Matriz{4,2}  & \Matriz{4,3} & \Matriz{4,4}
\end{array}
\right]
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### initial answer

(see a corrigendum at bottom of answer, in particular for sign in first row due to missing parentheses in the code)

You seem to need computations beyond the TeX built-in abilities (roughly up to 16383.99999 if using TeX capabilities for fixed-point evaluations).  If remaining beyond a total of 16 digits of precisions, LaTeX now incorporates out of the box the `xfp` abilities.  But with powers of integers for example  `1234^6` you need more than 16 digits of precision.

Some people have extended TeX with arbitrary precision calculations, I know of bigintcalc (only integers), apnum, and xint.  Here is an approach via xint:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}

\xintAssignArray{-100}{110}{120}{130}\to\X

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Matriz[1]{\Matriz@#1;}
% this stuff with #1#2 and #3#4 is only to allow space tokens
% in reasonable places in input,
% but I don't think they would matter (one would have to ask
% an xint knowledgeable user)
\def\Matriz@#1#2,#3#4;{\xinteval{\X{#1#2}^(#3#4)}}
\makeatother


A matriz $A$ é dada por: \\

$
A=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
     \Matriz{1,1}&\Matriz{1,2}  & \Matriz{1,3} & \Matriz{1,4}\\
     \Matriz{2,1}&\Matriz{2,2}  & \Matriz{2,3} & \Matriz{2,4}\\
     \Matriz{3,1}&\Matriz{3,2}  & \Matriz{3,3} & \Matriz{3,4}\\
     \Matriz{4,1}&\Matriz{4,2}  & \Matriz{4,3} & \Matriz{4,4}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However the `\Matriz` here is a macro which reevalutes on each use.  One would have to code something extra if you really want a kind of permanent structure; here only `\X` is used as a permanent 1-dim array.

Also this solution does not worry about the alignment in the columns, maybe look at siunitx for such things.

(update: I forgot in this original answer to reduce by 1 the column index, and more serious, I forgot parenthesis in case the number is negative so please simply replace `\xinteval{\X{#1#2}^(#3#4)}` by `\xinteval{(\X{#1#2})^(#3#4-1)}`)

Answer (score 0):

As `tikzmath` is limited in calculations due to TeX capacity. I propose using Asymptote or Python for calculations (*a piece of cake*); and then embbeded into LaTeX document (it's not *a piece of cake*, I must test more, and please comment to suggest me, since this thing is helpful for other situation).

**1. Calculation with Asymptote**

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
real[] x={-100,110,120,-130}; 
int n=x.length; write('n = ',x.length);
real G(int i, real t) {return t^i;}; 

// initialisation A as the identity
real[][] A=identity(n); 

for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)
A[i][j]=G(j,x[i]);

write('Now the matrix A is given by: ');
write(A);
```